# MySQL - Get the occurrence of couples of values in 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got a table with repeated X and Y couples:

```
------------------------
   ID   |   X   |   Y   
------------------------
   1       10      20
   2       20      10
   3       10      20
   4       30      20
   5       20      10
   6       20      10
```

I would like to count the frequency of the same `(X,Y)` couples like this:

```
--------------------------
  X   |   Y   |   COUNT   
--------------------------
  20     10         3
  10     20         2
  30     20         1
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT  X, 
        Y, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT X, Y) AS FREQUENCY 
FROM `ordini` 
GROUP BY X, Y
ORDER BY `FREQUENCY` DESC
```

But the result is not what I expected: FREQUENCY returned is 1 for all the couples.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: you killed it with distinct

Comment: @Veljko89 feeling asleep this morning, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use this `COUNT(DISTINCT X, Y)` as `DISTINCT` removes all the same records and you are getting single value for same X,Y that's why you are getting 1

```
SELECT  X, 
        Y, 
        COUNT(*) AS FREQUENCY 
FROM ordini
GROUP BY X, Y
ORDER BY FREQUENCY DESC
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beeff/2